# Is the flat design out of fashion?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, design, software, flat-design

We are planning on building a software and we had this discussion regarding the design. Someone mentioned that the flat design pattern is out of fashion, but when I asked them what replaced it, there was no clear answer.

What are your ideas about the flat design pattern? And is it really out of fashion? Specifically, are there usability or other UX issues with the flat design pattern?

Comment: This is more of a design issue than a UX issue, so you'll have better luck asking on that StackExchange: graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: fashion is not really a good basis for making design decisions, because it changes.

Comment: As for the edit, there are plenty of posts relating to UX of flat design. Some of them can be found on the sidebar and rest here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+flat+design

Answer (score 2):

Flat design isn't necessarily out of fashion, it's just that interactive elements seem to be more clear and easily identifiable with shadows and other 3D-esque design techniques.

If you're looking for a newer trend, check out Material design. This is what Google uses.

Comment: Here's an article from NNG that supports your answer: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/flat-design/